# MySQL Query Order By Cluase taking too much time

Tags: mysql, doctrine-orm

I have a query which is taking only .001 sec without the Order by part. But When i add order by in the query it takes time around .736 sec. that is too much time. I have indexed that column but its not working as expected.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
n0_.id AS id0, n0_.published_at AS published_at1
FROM
news n0_
    INNER JOIN
news_translations n1_ ON n0_.id = n1_.translatable_id
WHERE
((n0_.unpublished_at IS NOT NULL
    AND (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP >= n0_.published_at
    AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP < n0_.unpublished_at))
    OR (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP >= n0_.published_at
    AND n0_.unpublished_at IS NULL))

    AND  
        (n0_.status = 1
     AND n0_.content_type_id = 1)
      AND  n1_.locale = 'zh_CN'
     and n0_.id NOT IN (139476 , 226, 225, 224, 223, 218, 213, 69, 65, 62)   
GROUP BY n0_.id
#ORDER BY n0_.published_at DESC
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0;
```

Here is the output of SHOW KEYS:

```
Table   Non_unique  Key_name    Seq_in_index    Column_name Collation   Cardinality Sub_part    Packed  Null    Index_type
news    0   PRIMARY 1   id  A   139656  NULL    NULL        BTREE
news    0   UNIQ_1DD399501204232D   1   comment_box_id  A   139656  NULL    NULL    YES BTREE
news    1   IDX_1DD39950510C33D5    1   approval_type_id    A   4   NULL    NULL    YES BTREE
news    1   IDX_1DD399501A445520    1   content_type_id A   36  NULL    NULL    YES BTREE
news    1   IDX_1DD39950A76ED395    1   user_id A   4   NULL    NULL    YES BTREE
news    1   IDX_1DD3995042A9A1DE    1   smiley_group_id A   4   NULL    NULL    YES BTREE
news    1   IDX_1DD39950B3FE509D    1   survey_id   A   4   NULL    NULL    YES BTREE
news    1   IDX_1DD3995029C1004E    1   video_id    A   4   NULL    NULL    YES BTREE
news    1   IDX_1DD399501CDF82CA    1   cover_image A   4   NULL    NULL    YES BTREE
news    1   IDX_1DD399504E7AF8F     1   gallery_id  A   4   NULL    NULL    YES BTREE
news    1   IDX_1DD399506048130B    1   home_position_id    A   4   NULL    NULL    YES BTREE
news    1   news_published_at_index 1   published_at    A   139656  NULL    NULL        BTREE
```

Comment: try investigating with the `query execution plan` .See how explain work [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html)

Comment: if you launch the query with the order by ASC instead of DESC have the same execution time?

Comment: How many rows query return if you omit LIMIT? I presume a lot. Sort is an expensive operation and take long time, also it's executed before trimming  results by LIMIT.

Comment: @Matteo Yes the time is almost the same.

Comment: @JánStibila there are 136313 without the limit.

Comment: @Matteo the explain result of the published_at is
Field,Type,Null,Key,Default,Extra
published_at,datetime,NO,MUL,NULL

Comment: Well, it's quite a lot to sort. Are your data in table somehow sort by published_at? if yes, you can use that. Otherwise you need to cut your results before sorting.

Comment: @JánStibila Your suggestion has worth. I have tested it with the id field its working amazing. please answer now ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort is an expensive operation, so ordering many rows will take time. One approach is to cut results before ordering, but that's not always possible.

Also think what other patterns can be found in your table and use that. I am pretty sure, that your data are always ordered by id ascending (probably published time as well). As I see, you are ordering by published time, so if data are naturally ordered by this column in your table, you can use that to your advantage.
But make sure that is the case, so there are no exceptions. For example, if you always use NOW() when inserting new row, then there is big chance, that they are ordered.